# Nextjs, how to redirect from _app.tsx

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am doing a routing based on the role of the user in nextjs. I did one hook which returnes true or false if a user is allowed to navigate in a route. I want to intercept that into _app.tsx file so I did the following thing:

*_app.tsx*

```
const App: React.FC<{
  Component: React.FC;
  pageProps: Record<string, any>;
}> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const user =
    typeof localStorage !== 'undefined'
      ? (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') ?? 'null') as
          | User
          | { role: undefined })
      : null;
  
  //useRouteProvider returns true/false
  const isUserAllowedOnRoute = useRouteProvider(router.pathname, user?.role);

  if (!isUserAllowedOnRoute) {
    window.location.replace('/');
    // I also tried router.push('/') and Router.push('/') but I can't use that into this file. 
  }
  return (
    //...
  );
};

export default App;
```

In this case the error is `ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Based on the value of `isUserAllowedOnRoute`, how can I redirect to a certain route from here?

Comment: Maybe try wrapping all your code in an `useEffect`?

Comment: The problem is that I am not into a window, so window instance doesn't exist. In fact it throws me ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: The `window` object will be available inside the `useEffect`. As @MaxProgramming mentioned, try moving the redirect logic into a `useEffect`.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes it is true, but it shows me the page. If I go to a route only for one specific role and I am not logged in, it shows me that page for 1 second and it is not really nice to see

Comment: That's expected if you're doing client-side redirects. If you don't want the flash to happen move the redirect to the server-side (using `getServerSideProps` for instance) instead. Or don't show any content _until after_ the check for the redirect is done.

Comment: @MARiVS I would suggest going this way:

1. Add `loading` boolean state. (loading = true)
2. In return, check if `loading` is true, show a loading indicator.
3. In `useEffect`, check if the user exists, if it does, redirect the user.
4. If the user does not exist, set `loading` to false, and in the return, show user not found